# Find exact location of <included> file in C++ at compilation time

Tags: c++, macos, include

I am compiling a C++ file which includes `glui.h`. This in turn includes `glut.h` like so:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

My C++ file successfully compiles, using CMake and a Makefile.

However, I am unsure as to which copy of `glut.h` is being included. Is it possible to discover, at compile time, the location on my computer at which `GLUT/glut.h` has been found? If it makes a difference, I am compiling this under OSX 10.8 with g++.

(This obviously has a specific answer relative to OpenGL and GLUT, but I am especially  looking for a general answer which will help me to resolve ambiguous `include`s in the future)

Comment: Modify one of then so it throws an error, then recompile.

Comment: I think passing `-v` to g++ will also print include paths.

Comment: In case of visual studio the flag is called /showIncludes . It's also available under C/C++->Advanced in the file properties.

Comment: @Laserallan: Does Visual studio work on OS-X?

Comment: Obviously I didn't read the question careful enough. Anyway the title doesn't say anything about osx so if anyone ends up here with google it might be useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add -E flag to g++/gcc when you compile, you will get preprocessor output, which will tell you what header files are included with full path.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem just the other day, and solved it like this:

```
$ gcc -E writefile.c | grep stdio.h
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 29 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 35 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 37 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 45 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 65 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 75 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 76 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
```

(Obviously, the file I was looking for at work wasn't `stdio.h`, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pragma message](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to indicate source file locations, along with other diagnostic info.

```
#pragma message "Using file at: " __FILE__
```

Comment: Or `#error`, or some compilers have a `#warning` extension, but you can't always modify a header to put that in.

Comment: Of course, that requires already knowing all the possible locations of the file you wish to identify. It also requires that you have permission to modify them.